# Convert a Sage multivariate polynomial into a univariate one

Tags: polynomials, sage

I am trying to implement [Schoof's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%27s_algorithm) in Sage.

I have multivariate polynomials `f(x, y)` with coefficients in
a finite field `F_q`, for which the variable `y` only appears
in even powers (for example `f(x, y) = x * y^4 + x^3 * y^2 + x`).

Furthermore, using an equation `y^2 = x^3 + A * x + B`,
I want to replace powers of `y^2` in the polynomial with
corresponding powers of `x^3 + A * x + B`,
so that the polynomial depends only on `x`.

My idea was this:

```py
J = ideal(f, y ** 2 - (x ** 3 + A * x + B))
f = R(J.elimination_ideal(y).gens()[0])
```

(`R` is a univariate polynomial ring).
My problem is, sometimes it works, sometimes it does not
(I don't know why).
Is there a better solution or standard solution?

Answer (score 0):

For counting points on elliptic curves,
the following resources might be useful:

- [SageMath constructions: algebraic geometry: point couting on curves](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/constructions/algebraic_geometry.html#point-counting-on-curves)
- [SageMath thematic tutorial on Schoof-Elkies-Atkin point counting](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/thematic_tutorials/explicit_methods_in_number_theory/elliptic_curves.html#schoof-elkies-atkin-point-counting)

Regarding polynomials, consider providing
an example that works and one that fails.

That might help analyse the problem and answer the question.

Note that [Ask Sage](https://ask.sagemath.org/)
has more experts ready to answer SageMath questions.